# One trip across two consecutive Schengen visas?

Tags: visas, schengen

I would like to consult you on a weird situation in which I might have to take a trip to the Schengen area that fall on two consecutive visas I have.

I (Chinese passport holder, student in UK university) am planning to travel to Germany 20-23 June to attend a friend's wedding. As I already have a tourist Schengen visa that lasts (rather unfortunately) exactly until 20 June I had to get another visa for the rest of the days of the trip.

I submitted the application to the German Embassy in London through VFS with the indication on the application form that I am entering the Schengen area on 20th (with all the booked flights, accommodation etc.). When I received my passport I found that I was granted a new tourist Schengen visa indeed, but starting from 21th June instead of 20th. Can I, with the two consecutive visas, enter Germany on 20 June and stay through to the 23 June? Are there cases/regulations that you have heard of regarding such situation?

Comment: Yes, you can, that's exactly how it's supposed to work, see my answer to the other question.

Comment: I see!!! Thank you so much for answering the question and for sharing the handbook - I wasn't aware of its existence!:)

Comment: Hey, I'm in the same situation. Did you face any problems? What handbook are you referring to?